# Recovery of quick cast and arcane attunements

Tags: dnd-3.5e

My Elven Duskblade is defending a cave with his guardsmen party against undead. We will probably get no rest all night. How would recovery of attunements and quick cast work? I know I won't recover spells without rest but haven't found any rules on recovery of SLA's or class abilities.

Comment: Great question, and one we have ... well, I can’t say we have an answer for it (the rules don’t say), but one we have answered as well as it can be answered. See the link for a solid discussion of what’s going on.